# Is there a way to shorten this command for finding your local ip address?

Tags: macos, bash

I am using

```
ifconfig | grep en0 -A 5 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

to find my system's local ip address. I am certain there is a way to shorten this.

Comment: `awk` can do what the last three are doing.

Comment: That is not helpful.

Comment: Is this for local host then -hostname -i should do?

Comment: Might I suggest that you prepare actual answers and post below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ipconfig getifaddr en0` assuming that `en0` is the network interface you're using.

If you aren't sure...

```
ipconfig getifaddr `route -n get default | grep interface | awk '{print $2}'`
```

is pretty bulletproof, but loses the conciseness.

Comment: You mean `awk '/interface/ { print $2 }'` without the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1):

Not shorter, but useful too:

```
echo $(/usr/sbin/arp $(hostname) | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}')
```